# Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. c# .NET5.0

Tags: c#, .net

Столкнулся с проблемой отправки POST запроса.
При отправке запроса посредством .NET5.0 приложения получаю "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.", при этом отправка такого же запроса через стороннюю утилиту Postman проходит успешно.

```
                        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                        form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(enpFile.FileData)), enpFile.FileName, enpFile.FileName);

                        form.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

                        HttpResponseMessage sendResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(sendUrl, form); //exception here
```

1. Пробовал добавить, не помогло

   ```
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => 
        {
            return true;
        };
   ```
2. Пробовал добавить, не помогло

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
> SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

и

> clientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 |
> SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13 | SslProtocols.None;

3. Пробовал добавить, не помогло

   ```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
        {
            return true;
        };
   ```

Операционка Windows server 2016
Сертификат у адреса валидный, цепочка тоже. Все сертификаты стоят в нужных местах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повторюсь, Postman успешно отправляет точно такой же запрос.
Fizdler также падает с ошибкой "А**утентификация не пройдена из-за закрытия транспортного потока удаленной стороной**."

Дебажил запросы:

- Такой запрос уходит при отправке через c#: https://pastebin.com/8QAJmDyF
- Такой запрос отдает Postman: https://pastebin.com/32f1GiB3

Comment: Попробуйте советы от сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008797/http-web-request-tls-1-3-with-c-sharp-net-core-3-1-exception-the-client-and-se

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы.
Спустя десяток вариантов, штудирования запросов оказалось, что проблема не на стороне сервера, а на стороне балансировщиков/firewall

Comment: Так а в чём именно проблема то была?